# Application launcher with tab-completion

Tags: xfce, launcher

**EDIT**:

Ok, fair enough - probably using a standalone launcher is the way to go as Daniel Andersson [suggest](https://superuser.com/a/414626/12998) below. But this leads to following questions:

Either;

1. How do I get bash-like command completion with <kbd>Tab</kbd> to work in xfrun4 *or*:
2. Is there some other launcher (for xfce) that opens instantly enough (as fast as xterm) does *not* need crapload of KDE or Gnome libs that has tab-completion?

For instantly enough reference:

```
$ time $(xterm echo)

real    0m0.064s
user    0m0.048s
sys     0m0.004s
```

**The original question was**:

Old habits die hard, so on my Linux desktop I launch applications by opening a terminal and running the (X) application from the command line. I would like to turn one of my Xterm windows into an application launcher so that I can just type `google-chrome` or `charm` and the application is launched in the background without suffixing the command with `&` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> followed by `bg`.

Is there an easy way to make an Xterm window / shell that runs all command in the background?
Preferably a script that I can just `source` (in bash) or even better, something that is run automatically when I *disembiggen* the font by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question really is "**I want an application launcher**", then there are plenty to choose from. It sounds like this is the easiest way to solve your *actual* problem. I use [`gmrun`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gmrun/) which is very light-weight and has completion. [Wikipedia keeps a bigger list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_desktop_application_launchers) of such applications. Bind a keyboard shortcut to one of these, and then you can simply issue this shortcut instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and run the program.

If you question is "**I don't want to have to type `&` to launch programs in the background in Bash**", then you could do a script such as

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
    read command
    ${command} &
done
```

When run, you can enter a command, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and it will be launched in the background.

If you want the shell to automatically think "ah, this is a graphical program that he wants to run in the background" and only then add a `&`, then you'd need to keep some sort of list on all these binary names, and it would most likely be a great annoyance to other operations.

If your question is "**How do I catch** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> **in xterm and act on it?**", then I don't know.

**All in all:** I strongly recommend to just use a stand-alone application launcher, and get used to the shortcut for that.

Comment: Ok. `gmrun` seems to be available in the default repositories and seems to be quick enough.